# PyMongo Look up Dictionary Value when Value is in Sub-dictionary

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, pymongo

I'm a total newbie to both Python and MongoDB, so please excuse what might be a silly question.

I Have the record below in MongoDB. 
Lars Torsk being the first name and last name of the record. 
Gunnar Torsk being the first name and last name of Lars' father.

```
{
    '_id': ObjectId('54840b59b6a1b322b042bde0'), 
    'First Name': 'Lars', 
    'Father': {'Last Name': 'Torsk', >'First Name': 'Gunnar', '_id': ObjectId('54840b59b6a1b322b042bddf')}, 
    'Aliases': ['rass'], 
    'Last Name': >'Torsk'
}
```

If I wanted to find all records of people with the first name Lars I would use:

```
for person in people.find({'First Name': 'Lars'}):
    print(person)
```

But if I want to find all records of people whom have father's whose name is Gunnar, what would I write?

I tried:

```
for person in people.find({'Father': {'First Name': 'Gunnar'}}):
    print(person)
```

But it returns no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [*dot notation*](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation):

```
for person in people.find({'Father.First Name': 'Gunnar'}):
    print(person)
```

See also:

- [Equality Match on Fields within an Embedded Document](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#equality-match-on-fields-within-an-embedded-document)